# How to reduce size of React app, created by CRA?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have started to develop my Application from Create React App, and when I tried to deploy it on Heroku, it failed because of the memory limit.
I have completed a React course where the author have used webpack and in the config file this problem was solved by using
`'source-map' : 'inline-cheap-module-source-map',`
in production build, but as I am using the default CRA react-scripts, I cannot figure out how to repeat this.

For reference, the above mentioned tutorial course can be found at https://github.com/matefellner/react-expensify)

*edit:
When pushing to heroku, the build succeeds but when I open the url it does not load and in the heroku logs it repeatedly says:

2023-02-11T22:24:28.985688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=772M(150.9%)
2023-02-11T22:24:28.988667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)